# WCF timeout issue but method successfully called

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an issue with WCF timing out. The strange thing is that my method is actually being called on the server, but the client call ton the object returned from CreateChannel() is timing out with an exception.

The entire error messsage:

This request operation sent to net.pipe://localhost/AndonServer did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:01:00).  The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  This may be because the service is still processing the operation or because the service was unable to send a reply message.  Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client.

I could just decrease the timeout setting to 5 seconds, say, but that's a bit dirty. Anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you elapsed the timeout period waiting for a reply from the server. By default, all calls in WCF have both a request and a reply, even `void` methods. The server needs to complete the call promptly so WCF will send a reply. Another is option is to use a [one-way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733035.aspx) call if the client does not require a reply from the server.